# Script finds the necessary file when running through IDLE, but cannot find the file when running through terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, scripting, raspbian

I have a python script that uses Selenium to get my grades for my classes every hour and sends me an email if my grades have been changed.

I have an external file that gets referenced to see if there has been any change since the last write.

When I test the program by pressing F5 when in the IDLE, it works just as intended. But when I go to my terminal and type `python3 /home/pi/Desktop/gradesNotification/script.py` it works all the way up until it needs to open the text file with my grades. I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'grades'
```

The text file is in the same folder as the script. The program works when ran through IDLE, but does not work when started from terminal.

Comment: @stovfl, the cwd is /home/pi

Comment: Do you see the difference? Your current directory is: `/home/pi` but your file is in `/home/pi/Desktop/gradesNotification`

Comment: @stovfl, yes I see it now! Haha I feel dumb for not realizing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File names are given with respect to `cwd`, the current working directory.  It's possible that your cwd in IDLE is the directory where the grades reside, but that your terminal window is elsewhere.  Try changing to the proper directory, or specify the full path of the `grades` file.

Another way is to have your program check its own location, and try to open `grades` from there.

Comment: Oh I see! When running from the IDLE, I am working from the directory of where the grades text file is. But when running from the terminal the working directory is /home/pi. 
I can either cd /gradesNotification, or in the .py file specify the exact path to the grades file, as you suggested. 
Thanks!

Comment: Right ... or have `script.py` ask where it resides, and use that path prefix to find `grades`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest fix to your problem would be specifying an absolute path to the grades file in your code:

```
"/home/pi/Desktop/gradesNotification/grades"
```

However, it would not be very pretty or flexible - [here](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/) is a great article on handling file system access from Python using pathlib library.